# Compare dates on server for particular timezone

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, date

On the server i need to determine if two points in time are on the same day in respect of the clients local time.

The date on the server is saved in UTC:

Date A: 2019-10-24T22:00:00.000Z

Date B: 2019-10-25T17:00:00.000Z

In my local timezone (+2:00) these two dates are on the same day, but if i compare them on the server they are not.

Would i have to obtain the clients timezone on the server to compare the dates or is there another pattern to solve this problem?

How would i create a date with the clients timezone to compare?

Comment: "*Would i have to obtain the clients timezone…*" of course, otherwise how will you be able to determine if they are on the same local day?

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving **UTCDATE** on the server then the following code will help you as you just need to pass current Timezone offset in minutes as follow

```
DECLARE @Offset as int = 300    
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, CONVERT(int,@Offset), GETUTCDATE())
```

Comment: i'm using mongodb and i don't want to add a fixed offset because it could change, (i.e. daylight saving time), but thank you anyway

Comment: There is another way in jquery plugin **momentjs**, google it

Answer (score -1):

You can use momentjs timezone, to tackle this problem
https://momentjs.com/timezone/
Where you can convert your server time , to your timezone before doing any calculations.

the best approach is to save timestamp in the server which is the milliseconds after epoch, that way you are always on the same page

Comment: ok i'll check momentjs/timezone, i just don't know yet how to obtain the clients time zone on the server...